# How to join two key values from map in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `List<Map>`:

```
var listMap = [
        {
          "label": "Title",
          "align": "left",
          "width": 50
        },
        {
          "label": "Date Created",
          "align": "left",
          "width": 50
        },

];
```

I want to join `label`, `align` and `width` with `|`
So the final result is of type `List<String>` :

```
var finalResult = ["Title|left|50", "Date Created|left|50"];
```

How can i achieve `finalResult`?

Comment: `listMap.map((m) => m.values.join('|'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this

```dart
var listMap = [
        {
          "label": "Title",
          "align": "left",
          "width": 50
        },
        {
          "label": "Date Created",
          "align": "left",
          "width": 50
        },

];
  var newList = [];
  for (var e in listMap) {
    newList.add(e.values.join('|'));
  }
  print(newList);
```

Also @pskink answer is correct to!